# How to delete an object after 24hrs since creation of the same

Tags: django, database, django-models, celery

I want to delete an instance after 24 hours since that instance has been created how to do that with celery

How can i start the "TIMER" after the creation of an instance?

I want something like Snapchat

Comment: have a look at Celery http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depends on the scale and your needs.

You will have to use django-celery-beat for periodical tasks:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#beat-custom-schedulers

I would honestly create a celery task that would run every 3-5 minutes.

`models.py`

```
   class Foo(models.model):
       created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_add_now=True)
       expiration_date = models.DateTimeField()
```

`views.py`

```
import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

def add_foo():
    # Create an instance of foo with expiration date now + one day
    Foo.objects.create(expiration_date=timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1))
```

`tasks.py`

```
from celery.schedules import crontab
from celery.task import periodic_task
from django.utils import timezone

@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(minute='*/5'))
def delete_old_foos():
    # Query all the foos in our database
    foos = Foo.objects.all()

    # Iterate through them
    for foo in foos:

        # If the expiration date is bigger than now delete it
        if foo.expiration_date < timezone.now():
            foo.delete()
            # log deletion
    return "completed deleting foos at {}".format(timezone.now())
```

Comment: Is there any other way to accomplish this, without celery. Just wanna know the options ;) or task queuing is the only way

Comment: @manishadwani Your question asked how should it be done via `celery` and has the `celery` tag. Make sure to edit the question so that it reflects that too. Other possible solution is to setup a cron job that would run a `manage.py` command via bash, that would do the same thing. Celery is built for use cases like these. I would advise you do this via celery, but if someone else has an alternative wait for them to respond! :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, i would take a look  at this

Comment: No problem, tag me if you need more help or you edit the question!

Comment: @user1 Unsure what language you're using or what you're implying (while I really do "You're funny" but as a derogatory term), but enjoy the flag and have a nice day!